# Explain me this syntax a,b=['apple','banana'] in python

Tags: python, string, list

```
a,b=['apple','banana']
```

I want to know that how the above syntax works and returns different strings 'apple' and 'banana' to a and b respectively indeed of returning a=['apple','banana'] and b=['apple','banana']

Comment: You know how it works. Are you asking *why* it works that way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remember that `a,b,c,d,e = 1,2,3,4,5` works as well.  It's a Python feature that it "unpacks" multiple values into multiple recipients.

Comment: `a = b = ['apple', 'banana']` does what you want

Comment: To assign the same list to `a` and `b`, it's `a = b = ['apple', 'banana']`.

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

> [If the target is an iterable] with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, [...] the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets.

`[a, b]` is an iterable with the same number of items as `['apple', 'banana']`, so `a` is assigned `apple` and `b` is assigned `banana`.